# why we should not exted BaseException class?

Tags: python

Why we should not extend BaseException class for creating our own Exception rather than extending Exception class in Python2.7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at [Exception hierarchy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

The only exceptions deriving from `BaseException` are `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit`. They are exception that **shouldn't be caught by accident**. That's why they're different.

Quote from [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/exceptions.html#KeyboardInterrupt):

> The exception inherits from BaseException so as to not be accidentally caught by code that catches Exception and thus prevent the interpreter from exiting.

This is also why you shouldn't use `try: ... except: ...` without specifying exception type.

Comment: thanks for responding my question. i have found some answer that in BaseException there is a finally block which is having __exit__() method which leads to exit the application. this is the reason we should not extend BaseException rather than Exception class...

Comment: This makes no sense. Exception extends BaseException, so Exception has `__exit__()`. In fact, any uncaught exception would exit the application. Can you throw me a̶n̶ ̶e̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ a link?

Comment: `__exit__()` is a context manager hook and does not exit the application. `sys.exit()` exits the application.